# Looking for the correct english term for

Tags: logic, proof

I just remembered a conversation I had (in german) about 18 years ago and the other person used the (german) term "All Theorie", which in this context was **not** related to the theory of everything but instead it is about the fact, that a proof can be shown not to be a valid proof, if it can prove any other hypothesis just as well (e.g. the opposite hypothesis or something entirely unrelated). I was not sure what the definition and the English term for this logical mistake is, nor can I remember a canonical example.

I tried to google the term but it seems my search always leads to the TOE instead of what I am looking for.

Can anyone here help me out?

**EDIT**
Maybe I should give a (hopefully not all too flawed) example of what I mean. In the dark ages, the inquisition believed to "proof" witchcraft of a person by means of torture. But they could have "proven" any other theory with the same flawed method. For example, they could have made them confess they are actually pink, flying bunnies in disguise. And because that is so, the "proof" is flawed.

Comment: Inconsistent ??

Comment: But what does it mean "all" in german?

Comment: Does it mean "every" (Alles) ? If so, how can we understand the locution "every theory" out of context ?

Comment: "All" means "every", yes.

Comment: But the context is logic (I think not) or philosophy of science (a theory that does not exclude anything)?

Comment: let P be a proof to H1. Now, you can apply P to H2, where H2 contradicts H1 but there is no other way to show, that P is flawed.

Comment: See [Karl Popper](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/popper/#ProbDema): "Every genuine scientific theory then, in Popper’s view, is *prohibitive*, in the sense that it forbids, by implication, particular events or occurrences. " And see [Falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability): "A theory is scientific if and only if it divides the class of basic statements into the following two non-empty sub-classes: (a) the class of all those basic statements with which it is inconsistent, or which it prohibits—this is the class of its potential falsifiers 1/2

Comment: (i.e., those statements which, if true, falsify the whole theory), and (b) the class of those basic statements with which it is consistent, or which it permits (i.e., those statements which, if true, corroborate it, or bear it out)." 2/2

Comment: Wikipedia calls it [proving too much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_too_much) fallacy.

Comment: You could consider the term "promiscuous" for describing this phenomenon.

Comment: @Conifold So far, I think your reference comes closest to what I am looking for. Using Curry Howard correspondence, the false "proof" would be something like `(defun prove-everything (hypothesis object) t)` Which would mean, that the proof does not even use the hypothesis and the object of the hypothesis for its result.

Comment: A famous historical example of proving too much is Anselm's ontological argument for God's existence. [Gaunilo replaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaunilo_of_Marmoutiers#The_%22Lost_Island%22_refutation) God in it with "the most perfect island", and suggested that if the form of the ontological argument were valid it would prove the island's existence too.